I am not able to call a function in Javascript from browser
Code Snippet
When I click on Write button nothing is happening. Also it is showing an error 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')' in browser console.
I was expecting that after I click on 'Write' button on browser, the function in Javascript file will be called. First it will show a prompt with "Inside Function" after that it will print "Hello All" on console.

Note: addEventListener expects a function as the second argument - next time, post the CODE in the question, not a picture of it - your issue is that your script runs BEFORE the element exists.

Simply add defer to the script tag <script defer src="main.js"></script> or else add the script to the end of the body removing it from the head
